# How to avoid page reload on back navigation..?

Tags: nativescript

Every time we navigate back from a page, the previous page reloads on top of existing data. this causes a bad user experience, how do we avoid refresh on back navigation.

Comment: Are you talking about the `loaded` event? If then yes, that is expected. If you are calling any APIs in loaded event, then you might want to move it to navigatedTo / navigatedFrom events Or simply remove the loaded event listener once you are done.

Comment: I am having the call on ngOnInit and i have no pages. Even if i use navigatedTo / navigatedFrom the API will be called every time right, how do i persist the data on screen without reloading...?

Comment: ngOnInit is supposed to run only once for component life time, can you share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced?